# Parse string in XML with xslt

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I have the following data in an XML file.

```
<Message number=1>
    <Field name="option1" type="Enumerated" desc="Interpret this field as the Number to which the Sector is slaved:  0 = Some Text for option 1 = A Different text option  2 = Yet another text option 8 – 10 = Reserved."/>
    <Field name="option2" type="Enumerated" desc="Interpret this field as data rate  4 = 2Mbit 5 = 1Mbit 6 = .5MBit"/>
</Message>
<Message number=2>
    <Field name="option3" type="Enumerated" desc="Interpret this field as the altitute.  0 = 100 feet 1 = 200 feet  2 = 300 feet 3 – 5 = SPARE."/>
</Message>
```

I want to parse the desc attribute to the following xml format:

```
<Enumerations>
    <Enumeration name="option1">
        <Enumerator value="0" name="Some Text for option"/>
        <Enumerator value="1" name="A Different text option"/>
        <Enumerator value="2" name="Yet another text option"/>
        <Enumerator value="8" name="Reserved"/>
        <Enumerator value="9" name="Reserved"/>
        <Enumerator value="10" name="Reserved"/>
    </Enumeration>
    <Enumeration name="option2">
        <Enumerator value="4" name="2Mbit"/>
        <Enumerator value="5" name="1Mbit"/>
        <Enumerator value="6" name=".5MBit"/>
    </Enumeration>
    <Enumeration name="option3">
        <Enumerator value="0" name="100 feet"/>
        <Enumerator value="1" name="200 feet"/>
        <Enumerator value="2" name="300 feet"/>
        <Enumerator value="3" name="SPARE"/>
        <Enumerator value="4" name="SPARE"/>
        <Enumerator value="5" name="SPARE"/>
    </Enumeration>
<Enumerations>
```

The problems I'm having is that my data xml file (which is over 4K lines) has different start characters( : or , or " ") for the enumeration portion of the string.

I though that I might be able to use `xsl:analyze-string` but I have been unable to determine the proper regular expression.

Comment: If the "xxxx" stands for different strings (of differing lengths) in different instances, please let your example show that. Otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: Probably need two regex, One to grab the overall data `name="([^"]+)"[^>]+?desc="([^"]+)"` and another to parse capture group 1 for value = name parts. Then construct a Enumeration from the pieces.